# How to solve vector equation $\textbf{x}+2(\textbf{x}^T\cdot\textbf{a})\cdot\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-learning

How can I analytically/symbolically solve the following vector equation
$$\textbf{x}+2(\textbf{x}^T\cdot\textbf{a})\cdot\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$$

where $\textbf{x}$ is the unknown column vector of real values, $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are known column vectors of real values.

Comment: Cannot you just consider each row of the system? And what do you mean by solving? It is a system of non-linear equations

Comment: what is $\mathbf x^T\cdot\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf x$ supposed to mean?

Comment: I guess the scalar value of $x^\top a$ multiplies the overall vector $x$, but it should not indeed be a guess but should be formulate better in the question :)

Comment: @VanBaffo Unfortunately I cannot consider each element of $x$ separately, as I intend to use the solution in the kernel trick.

Comment: This is a system of quadratic equations in multiple variables which are generally not analytically solvable.

Comment: I think you mean $\textbf{x}+2(\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{a})\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$, which for $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}\ne0$ has solutions $\textbf{x}=k\textbf{b}$ with $2(\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b})k^2+k-1=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $x+2a^⊤x⋅x = (1+2a^⊤x)x = b$, we immediately see that a necessary condition for the equation to be solvable is that $x$ must be parallel, i.e. a scalar multiple of $b$.

So let $x=λb$, then we have

$$\begin{aligned}
   (1+2λa^⊤b)λb &= b
\\⟺ ((1+2λa^⊤b)λ - 1)b &= 0
\\⟺ b=0∨ (1+2λa^⊤b)λ - 1 &=0
\end{aligned}$$

The latter case reduces to a quadratic equation in a single variable

$$ (2a^⊤b) λ^2 + λ - 1 =0$$

which gives us the solutions $λ=\frac{-1±\sqrt{1+8a^⊤b}}{4a^⊤b}$.

In particular, we have that a real solution only exists if the following criteria are met:

1. $a\not\perp b$, i.e. $a$ is not orthogonal to $b$.
2. $a^⊤b≥-1/8$.

If $a^⊤b=-1/8$, the solution is uniquely given by $x=2b$.

Comment: If $a\perp b$ we have $x = b$.